# pipenv "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement" from private pypi when pip can install it just fine

Tags: python, pip, pipenv

I recently built and uploaded a new sdist to my private pypi and I'm getting

> CRITICAL:pipenv.patched.notpip._internal.index:Could not find a
>   version that satisfies the requirement mypackage [list of versions
>   that does not include the version I just added]

I ran `pipenv install` with `-vvvv` and I noticed that pipenv was printing

> ['/myvirtualenvpath/bin/pip', 'install', '--verbose', '--upgrade',
>   '"mypackage==myversion"', '-i', 'https://pypi.org/simple',
>   '--extra-index-url', 'https://myindex/pypi/pypi/simple']

So naturally I ran that command from within the pipenv venv to see what the error is but it installed the package right away.

The index is clearly set right, especially since this was a nonissue until I uploaded this new sdist. I went on the browser to my pypi index and the version is indeed there.

Answer (score 0):

I inspected the contents of my pypi index more closely and I noticed that it was missing a .whl file. Running `python setup.py bdist_wheel upload` solves the problem.

So before every other version had `my-package-my-version-py2.py3-none-any.whl`. Generating and uploading this file to pypi solved this problem.